# Ruby On Rails Master-Slave Postrgres Databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, replication, master-slave, slony

I am currently setting up a master-slave app using Ruby on Rails that needs to have a Master-Slave backend.  I'm currently looking at using [Slony](http://www.slony.info/) for the replication component, and [Masochism](http://github.com/technoweenie/masochism) for handling the read/write connections to the different DBs.

This is my first time setting up master-slave DBs with Ruby on Rails, and these are the two options I've seen come up the most.  Have you worked with a better plugin for this situation in the past?  The limit to the number of slaves in Slony isn't an issue for the situation, I should realistically only need one or two.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Ruby, it would be sin not to try out [rubyrep](http://www.rubyrep.org/).

Comment: Note: It seems rubyrep is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

i personally use MySQL so my basic implementation might not work, but i used Masochism too and moved to [DataFabric](http://github.com/fiveruns/data_fabric/tree/master), which supports more slaves and sharding as well as replication mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

We used Slony and Masochism, but switched to [Londiste](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Londiste_Tutorial) and [DataFabric](http://github.com/fiveruns/data_fabric) and haven't looked back.